# ImportError: Failed to import test modul

Tags: python, django

here is my project structure :

[image]

```py
# Create your tests here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

from g_attend.website.models import Profile


class TestIndex(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username='user', password='pass')
        Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, type="Admin", full_name="Ahmed Wagdy")

    def test_visit_unauthorised(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
```

I've used `python manage.py startapp` to create both apps `website` and `panel` 
Now when I added tests to `website.tests.py` as follows :

```py
# Create your tests here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

from g_attend.website.models import Profile


class TestIndex(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username='user', password='pass')
        Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, type="Admin", full_name="Ahmed Wagdy")

    def test_visit_unauthorised(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
```

but I try to run tests I get this error: `ImportError: Failed to import test module: website.tests`

Comment: where is your manage.py, I couldnt see that.

Comment: @engin_ipek edited with a wider screenshot

Comment: if my eyes don't trick me, your manage.py is inside your website module. So "python manage.py test tests" should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**g_attend** over here is a module, but the django app named **'website'** is outside, that is in the *root* directory like all apps exist.

In your `tests.py` inside website, change the following import

`from g_attend.website.models import Profile` to

`from .models import Profile` or maybe

`from website.models import Profile`

This will fix the **'cannot import module'** problem.